# How can I make an injected element responsive on a non-responsive page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design

I'm building a React app that can be injected in a page as a normal html element. I ran into the issue of webpages that **don't use** the viewport meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. I am required to make my injected element scale properly on mobile devices, even though the page it is injected into doesn't.

I've tried adding classes that represent the current viewport width and using them similarly to media queries, however I can not deal with the font sizes not scaling properly, since using rems would use the page font size which itself doesn't scale.

I even resorted to using `transform: scale((window.innerWidth / window.screen.width).toFixed(3))` but that is hardly controllable.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your component in iframe?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the project specification prohibits me from using an iframe.

Comment: It this technical constrain or what? I mean is there are some other technical problems that iframe introduces? Because for me iframe is designed to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same when I first encountered the problem but unfortunately due to some other technical constrains I was told to find another solution.